# Extract Xpath local-name of parent node of the grandchildren by knowing only the root node name

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

The problem lies on the fact that I am not able to extract a specific child node local-name when I only know the parent node name, example below:

I know that the parent node (root) is "companies" even for other tables i always know the first one. My question is how to know what is the local-name of the parent node that contains the grandchildren.

*//companies/*/child::node()/text()*   -> this returns the grandchildren

The answer should be **industry**. Would that be any generic logic that would also give me the same thing but for example the parent node local-name of the grand grand children , so a structure of 3 nested tables.

```
    <companies>
        <id>3</id>
        <display_name>abc</display_name>
        <fun_name>12345</fun_name>
        <industry>
            <name>System</name>
            <level_1>45</level_1>
            <level_2>4510</level_2>
            <level_3>451030</level_3>
            <level_4>45103020</level_4>     
        </industry>
        <abc>xxxxx</abc>
    </companies>
```

Thank you
Regards
JP

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
local-name(parent::*)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the parent localname of grandchildren of `companies`:

`local-name(//companies/*/*/..)`

For great-grandchildren:

`local-name(//companies/*/*/*/..)`

and so on

An alternate way to express this would be:

`local-name(//companies/*[*])`

and for great-grandchildren

`local-name(//companies/*[*/*])`